# Build Managment With Maven and HK2

Tags: java, maven, build, build-process, build-automation

So far, I have created a web application using JAX-RS ([Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/)) and Maven as build and dependency managment, but for this question, I'm not sure it matters. I'm using [h2k](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/) as DI framework. It works fine and I can package the application as a WAR which can be deployed to a tomcat server (both locally and remote).

The application is configured using jersey's ResourceConfig, where I also configure my AbstractBinder (for h2k) to bind my @Inject to concrete instances. So far so good. Now I want to use Jetty (or grizzly) as an embedded server for local development (by mvn jetty:run), and automate the build of the war for remote deployment. I want to use different classes (injected by hk2) depending on the environment (eg. fake email sender, on test server), and this is where I'm stuck. How do I specify which environment I'm running in and how do I specify which classes to use for each environment?

Maybe my problem is in my understanding of how all this works (Examples of actual build setups would be warmly welcomed). Normally I just use [AbstractFactory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), which I inject into my main method. My guess on how this should be done:

- I should create a properties / xml file for each environment, where I specify which implementations and properties should be used.
- When running or building, I should specify which environment I'm running in (for instance mvn build -ENVIRONMENT)